# Can I use 'and' operator in xsl for-each?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, foreach

Simply can I execute the following in xsl?

```
 <xsl:for-each select="trip/instance[.!=''] and trip/result[.!='']">
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Q: When I use select="" in for-each does it change the scope of my selector for the code I use inside for-each?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You can use 'and' in for-each loop, but not in the way you have mentioned (being not sure what exactly you want to achieve)**

I assume your requirements something like, either
1) You want to loop through `Trip` whose both child entities are (`instance` and `result`) not null,
In this case you have to write like this ..

```
<xsl:for-each select="trip[instance!='' and result!='']>
```

if any one among instance and result are null, then your loop doesn't enter the element namely, trip.

2) You want to seek through each `instance`and`result` children inside parent `trip` whose values are not null. In this case you Don't need `and` ..

```
<xsl:for-each select="trip/instance[.!=''] | trip/result[.!='']">
```

This will work.

Now answer to your Q ..
with FOR-EACH loop you can set the scope of selector ..

for-example:In case (1), scope of selector was "`root_name//trip`" and in case (2) scope of selector was "`root_name//trip/instance`" also "`root_name//trip/result`" ..

*I hope, I understood your question correctly and answered it as understandable ..*

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot use `and` in the `select` attribute.

You want to use the `union` operator: `|`, which behaves kind of like an **and** and kind of like an **or**, depending on how you think about it.

It will give you a distinct list of both sets of nodes and will return them in the document order that it finds them(not all `instance` and then all `result` elements).

```
 <xsl:for-each select="trip/instance[.!=''] | trip/result[.!='']">
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Inside the `for-each` the context will switch between each of the selected nodes during each iteration.  You can access the current node with `.` or `current()`.

Comment: +1 for explanation on UNION operator .. and for the point "DEPENDING ON HOW YOU THINK ABOUT IT"