# Testing for 2 conditions under group-starting-with in <xsl:for-each-group>

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I need to test for 1 of 2 possible tags in a for-each-group.  Is this possible?  What is the correct syntax?

I tried "||" but got an error from the parser.  I'm using Saxon PE 9.3 in Oxygen 12.1.

Ex.

```
<xsl:param name="elements" as="element()*"/>    
<xsl:for-each-group select="$elements"
                group-starting-with="condition or condition" >
    <xsl:for-each-group>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to group starting with either of two element names, try

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$elements"
            group-starting-with="foo | bar">
```

Comment: I think that's what you're asking, but if you're actually asking about using boolean conditions, use `group-starting-with="node()[condition1 or condition2]"`

Comment: No, that's exactly what I needed. I actually had just found the answer in this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219127/can-i-use-and-operator-in-xsl-for-each Thanks for the help!